# javascript can not prevent submit on JSP page, why?

Tags: java, javascript, php, jsp, validation

I have simple form and I want to submit button, but with confirmation, but in two cases form do submit, I cant stop submit even if I click cancel after confirm window appear

her is a code, why form always do submit? it enter to ELSE case, but do action:(

```
 <body>
        <h1>Test me</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitPost(btn) {
                var $result = false;
                $result = confirm('Are you sure???');
                if ($result === true) {
                    alert("Submit????? " + $result);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("Do not submit " + $result);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <%
           String token = request.getParameter("finalise");
           out.println("Set is " + token);    
        %>
        <form method="get" name="myform" action="index.jsp">       
            <button type="submit" id="SaveIt"  onclick="submitPost(this);" name="finalise" value="setme">TEST ME</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: `onclick="return submitPost(this);"`, however your button is of type submit, maybe you should consider changing it, and use javascript to actually submit?

Comment: I can change to button, but I need in success case send value from button

Comment: here I can use only java script and I do not know if I set button, how can i send value from button? do post or do get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript to stop form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the return value from your function where you call it:

```
<button type="submit" id="SaveIt"  onclick="return submitPost(this);" name="finalise" value="setme">TEST ME</button>
                                            ^^^^^^ here
```